# JOIN table on itself?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to build a query which is pulling records from a table **form_submission_values** which stores all name/value pairs alongside one another in the following structure:

```
SubmissionValueId | SubmissionId | FieldName | FieldValue
```

So I need to do a lookup within the table for all records where FieldName='payment' and FieldValue='stripe' to pull all records related to submissions paid by Stripe. I thereafter need to use that list of SubmissionIds to pull all name/value pairs from the *same table* which have one of those SubmissionIds - so I'm wondering is that a join on the same table? In layman's terms, rather than a db query, it would be:

- Pull a list of the SubmissionIds of all records which have a FieldName of "payment" whose FieldValue is set to "stripe" from **form_submission_values**
- Use each of those SubmissionIds to pull a list of all the other FieldName and FieldValues (also from **form_submission_values**) for which the "SubmissionId" matches one from the list

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT IN INCLUDE CLARIFICATION:

Here's how the data being stored and how I would (ideally) be able to access it.

Data is stored in the "form submissions data" table as follows:

```
SubmissionValueId | SubmissionId | FieldName | FieldValue
171991            | 10,727       | name      | Mr Person
171992            | 10,727       | payment   | stripe
171993            | 10,727       | email     | person@email.com
171994            | 10,727       | total     | 180.00
171995            | 10,727       | _STATUS   | 1
171996            | 10,728       | name      | Mr Man
171997            | 10,728       | payment   | stripe
171998            | 10,728       | email     | person2@email.com
171999            | 10,728       | total     | 150.00
172000            | 10,728       | _STATUS   | -1
172001            | 10,729       | name      | Mrs Lady
172002            | 10,729       | payment   | offline
172003            | 10,729       | email     | person3@email.com
172004            | 10,729       | total     | 120.00
172005            | 10,729       | _STATUS   | 1
172006            | 10,730       | name      | Mrs Person
172007            | 10,730       | payment   | stripe
172008            | 10,730       | email     | person4@email.com
172009            | 10,730       | total     | 125.00
172010            | 10,730       | _STATUS   | 1
```

And what I need to do is pull the values for each "email", "person" and "total" field where the associated "payment" field value (associated by them having the same "SubmissionId" value) is set to "stripe" AND the associated "_STATUS" field value is set to "1".  This will filter out anyone who didn't pay by stripe and also anyone who paid by Stripe but the payment didn't succeed.

So using the above data it would ideally return the following:

```
Submissionid | Name       | Email             | Total
10,727       | Mr Person  | person@email.com  | 180.00
10,730       | Mrs Person | person4@email.com | 125.00
```

Comment: please  update  your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Updated now as requested @scaisEdge

Comment: i have posted  a first suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For show all the result on the same row You should join several time the same table

```
  select c.Submissionid, c.FieldValue Name, d.FieldValue Email , e.FieldValue Total 
  from form_submission_values c 
  inner join ( 
  select a.SubmissionId
  from form_submission_values a
  inner join form_submission_values b 
        on   b.FieldName= '_STATUS'  
        AND  b.FieldValue = '1' 
        AND  a.FieldName = 'payment' 
        and  a.FieldValue = 'stripe'
        and  a.SubmissionId = b.SubmissionId 
  ) t on t.SubmissionId = c.Submissionid
  inner join form_submission_values d on  d.SubmissionId = c.Submissionid
        and d.FieldName = 'email' 
        and c.FieldName = 'name' 
  inner join form_submission_values e on  e.SubmissionId = c.Submissionid
        and e.FieldName = 'total'
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this now but getting a error "Unknown column a.FieldName in ON clause" - also i think line 10 should be eiter a.FieldName= or b.FieldName= rather than b.aFieldName=. Are you able to clarify?

Comment: answer updated . .  was  d.fieldName  and not a.  and for line 10 is  b.FieldName  you are right..

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately still getting the same error, seems to be line 7 causing the issue of "unknown column a.FieldName" on that first inner join?

Comment: answer updated .. in 3 parts  ..one change the sequence of the condition in subselect ON clause for check if the problem i related  to table alias  or to the column name  .. secodn change a wron = with an AND  . if you have the same problem .. then check for the real name for the FieldName column  . and 3  ..the last a.FieldName is e.FieldName

Comment: That latest version seems to have done the trick, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A self-join would work, but so would a simple sub-select.

```
SELECT
  SubmissionValueId,
  SubmissionId,
  FieldName,
  FieldValue
FROM
  Submission
WHERE
  SubmissionId IN (
    SELECT SubmissionId
    FROM Submission
    WHERE FieldName = 'payment' AND FieldValue = 'stripe'
  )
```

Additionally to the primary index over `SubmissionId, SubmissionValueId` it would be helpful to have a secondary index over `FieldName, FieldValue, SubmissionId` for this query.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance!